# Break out from relative parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm sure this cannot be done with CSS, since all what's inside `position: relative` will be inside of it. So I was wondering maybe there was a javascript solution.

Basically what I want to achieve is this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVL8W/3/
But if you wrap it up with relative container and fixed width it won't work like in this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVL8W/8/

And it must be in relative container, but those two elements must break out from it and work like in first link example. Is this possible somehow maybe with javascript? Note that I cannot remove relative parent container.

Comment: this can be done just with css only. define your container width and height and position accordingly.

Comment: The width is defined in 2nd example, the elements inside the div must be position absolutely like in 1st link and ignore the parent container's fixed width and go outside it's boundaries.

Comment: yes, it can go outside the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/ZVL8W/9/

```
HTML,BODY { 
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

.left-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    position:ABSOLUTE;
    top:50%;
    left:0px;
    margin-top:-50px
}
.right-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:0px;
    margin-top:-50px    
}
```

or this http://jsfiddle.net/ZVL8W/10/

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

.left-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:0px;
    margin-top:-50px
}
.right-box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    right:0px;
    margin-top:-50px    
}
```